# Is there a way to access WPF control properties (specifically a button's IsDefault) if I only have an AutomationElement?

Tags: c#, wpf, microsoft-ui-automation

I have an AutomationElement for a particular WPF Button in an external application from the WPF application that I am try to access. Is there a way to find out the button's IsDefault property?

I have tried to access the button's window's control through its handle, using `(Window)HwndSource.FromHwnd(hWnd).RootVisual`,where hWnd is the button's window's `NativeWindowHandle`, but `FromHwnd` returns null.

Comment: Is IsDefault an attached property?

Comment: @GregD I don't think so. [IsDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.isdefault%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  seems to be just a regular property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, you can't access a WPF control object in another process. You might be able to do something with a tool like Snoop. In this particular case, I see that when I set IsDefault to true, the AccessKey property on the button's automation element is "\r". Otherwise it is empty ("").

Comment: Unfortunately in my case, the AccessKey is set to something different. Would a button where IsDefault is true always have an AccessKey of "\r"?

Comment: @M_Tee Obviously it can be different if you set `AutomationProperties.AccessKey` to something else. This is just what I saw when testing a toy example.